# Blackberry Development on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, blackberry

I recently started creating applications for mobile devices and have successfully completed an application for the iPhone. I am now turning my attention to the Blackberry but haven't been able to find a convincing article or website that states that it can be done or a tutorial on how to do so. Can Blackberry apps be developed on Mac OS X? If yes, how do I go about doing so? Can anyone please point me in the right direction as I only have access to a Mac and really want to get this project on the road. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 12):

UPDATE:

RIM has released a MacOS Eclipse plug-in for Blackberry Development: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/macosx.jsp

While there is no built-in simulator, the plug-in DOES support USB tethered device debugging for the Torch 9800 handhelds.  I plan to get one; they are ~$499 w/no contract.  With a Torch and the new plug-in, Blackberry development is possible without using a VM. (Finally!)

PREVIOUS POST:

Building on MacOS works well once you set it up.  I've had less luck with the simulator.  On the whole though, being able to run Eclipse natively in MacOS and flip to a Windows VM only for debugging is a big win in my book.

You can get a MacOS version of preverify (see link below for details).  I do my development with Eclipse on MacOS X and use Ant to build BB apps.

This blog is excellent and has many of the details to get you started:
[http://www.azizuysal.com/2009/07/blackberry-development-on-mac-os-x.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20101113021200/http://www.azizuysal.com/2009/07/blackberry-development-on-mac-os-x.html) (original link is dead.  The "wayback machine" provides us with the original text content, but images and styling are lost to the sands of time.  Still worth a read.)

The tricky part is getting the simulator to work.  There is a Wine-based work-around, but on my computer, while the simulator was able to run under Wine, the LCD output was scrambled.

Currently, I build COD files from Mac, and my Ant build process drops them into a directory that is shared with a WinXP VM.  I can run the simulator stand-alone in this VM.  Debugging is also possible by installing Eclipse inside WinXP and pointing the debug configuration it at the source directories.

I've actually got a bit more magic.  I enabled some of the Java 1.5 features by compiling against 1.5 and then translating the bytecode to 1.3 prior to the preverify script. (Blackberry only speaks a barbaric 1.3 java, flashback to circa 1992).   It's not a silver bullet as some features still don't work, but it does cut down on the need to make everything an untyped Object reference.

Lately, I've been working on a x-platform framework to allow me to write app code once and build against both Android and Blackberry (both are Java).  The Android part was easy.  It's just a bitch to debug anything in Blackberry.  Someone working at RIM decided that Blackberry didn't need to keep Exception stack traces unless there was a catch(Throwable), and then they could do something bizarre, non-standard, and undocumented (catching Throwable behaves *weird*).  I've only kinda-sorta figured out a hack to get stack traces using JavaLoader.exe without breaking into the debugger, and it's barely worth it.

p.s., I now do x-platform development with a single code-base targeting Android, Blackberry, and Desktop.  Desktop is great for testing app functionality, with very little Blackberry on-device testing needed once features work in the desktop 'simulator' (a Swing GUI built for debugging our games).

Comment: BTW - the RIM released install tool for Mac OSX with Eclipse is really easy to use.  However, the detail notes in the BLOG referenced in this answer is really insightful.  I recommend reading that blog entry.

Comment: wow, that sucks.  not exactly the same, but ... http://cafebotero.wordpress.com/2008/05/25/blackberry-development-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: found a new link.  turns out a copy of the text was available on the wayback machine.  updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Even though certain components of the RIM development platform are java-based, such as the JDE - other components such as the preverifier and device simulators are implemented as native Windows executables.

Basically, the easiest way to do it is to install Windows on your Mac using Bootcamp or Parallels and run inside a real Windows environment on your Mac.

However, there are other "hackier" ways to do it using Wine, MacPorts, and a number of other tools - as an example see [this blog post](http://www.azizuysal.com/2009/07/blackberry-development-on-mac-os-x.htmlhttp://www.azizuysal.com/2009/07/blackberry-development-on-mac-os-x.html)