# blackberry development start confusion

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I am going to start blackberry development (java) but I am confused in these two things that, eclipse with blackberry plugin will be better or  BlackBerry® Java® SDK v7.0. My project is NFC related so which software will be ease for beginner and good for nfc development.and if any good pdf or blog for beginner then please share that.

Comment: Pleae read this StackOverFlow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988413/java-beginner-coding-on-macbook-pro-blackberry-app-building. it may help you.

Comment: Refer to the [Blackberry tag information wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/blackberry/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlackBerry JDE Plugin is the main tool for making native BlackBerry applications with java.
It is possible to make native apps for OS 7.0 with BlackBerry Plugin For Eclipse.

I guess you mean BlackBerry JDE when you speak about "BlackBerry Java SDK v7.0"

BlackBerry JDE is a legacy tool and it is not a convenient way to develop complex apps.
Even making "Hello world" on JDE is a non-trivial task for a novice BlackBerry developer.

Consider this resource for further reading: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/