# Use BlackBerry JRE 5.0.0 or previous on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I have my Windows work computer set up with JDE 5, but the plugin for the Mac OSX Eclipse on my home computer is JDE 6 and I can't seem to find a source to download it from.

I found a blog post about [MacOS BlackBerry development](http://www.azizuysal.com/2009/07/blackberry-development-on-mac-os-x.html), but it is from before the official MacOS plugin was released.  Anything new on this front?

Comment: I'm confused. Does the Blackberry plugin require JRE 5 or 6? It sounds like you're looking for a JRE for your Mac but can't find the right one.

Comment: The recent answers on this question point to the JDE 6 for MacOS.   Looks like the earlier JDEs are not yet available for Mac.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774832/installing-blackberry-eclipse-jde-plugin-on-mac-os-x/777729

Comment: Those post on that question are a little over a year old already, i was expecting there to be some updates on the matter, but seems it's just wishful thinking. Thanks for the answers anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you still looking for an answer to this question? RIM has released the update for the Mac Eclipse v 1.1.2 Plugin. You have to go to "Help > Install New Software ..." and type the url: http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java . It should come up with options for the BlackBerry Java Plug-in Category. Clicking the arrow will reveal the other OS component packs (4.5 - 6.0). Install these (will take a while).

After this, go to the folder where your Eclipse plugins are located. You'll see the folders for the component packs (e.g. "net.rim.ejde.componentpack"). Copy the net.../components/bin folder from the 6.0 component pack to the other versions' components folder (backup the old one first).

In the components folder, there will be a BlackBerry.ee file. Copy the one from the 6.0 component pack into the other versions' components folder (again, backup the original). Open the new .ee file in a WYSIWYG text editor and change the version information to be accurate to the current component pack's version (e.g. 6.0.0.29 changes to 5.0.0.25).

In Eclipse, you need to add a system library. Open the Preferences and go to the Java > Installed JREs menu and click "Add...". When the window pops up, click "BlackBerry Execution Environment VM." For definition file, this is the BlackBerry.ee file for the version of the JRE you are adding. Name the JRE appropriately (e.g. BlackBerry 5.0). Next, click "Add External JARs..." and navigate to the net.../components/lib folder. Select the net_rim_api.jar file. Click finish and you should be good to go. (Repeat for other versions as necessary).

All that's left to do is to specify the correct JRE in your project properties (Java Compiler > {Click} Installed JREs link). Then, make sure the correct version is selected. Also, make sure there is only one JRE listed in the Project Explorer (newbie lesson learned).

Hope that helps if you still needed it to.

I should also add that I'm running my simulators on Windows via Parallels.

Comment: For anyone following this, this answer and the link provided by Stuart Tevendale (3/3/12) are identical and both work. Stuart's link "FYI: Blackberry JDE 4.6 setup on Mac" is slightly easier to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case it saves anyone else wasting half a day, ["FYI: Blackberry JDE 4.6 setup on Mac"](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/FYI-Blackberry-JDE-4-6-setup-on-Mac/m-p/1412885#M181733) on the BlackBerry support forums explains how to use the older Blackberry JREs with Eclipse on the Mac.

Comment: This answer is identical to the accepted answer by 'smoothk10' (11/24/10) and both answers are correct. Instructions in the BlackBerry link in THIS answer are slightly easier to follow IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

RIM has only released an Eclipse Plugin on OS X.  The JDE is Windows-only and probably will always be Windows-only (RIM is trying to phase out the JDE and is encouraging all developers to move to the Eclipse platform).

Keep in mind that the Eclipse plugin for OS X is still VERY new and still has some rough edges - I tried it out and it crashed on more than one occasion!  Also, there is no simulator available on OS X yet so you'll need a physical device to deploy and test on (I think it has to be a 9800 but I could be wrong).  RIM has promised a simulator on OS X but probably not for another 6 months or so.

Comment: Thanks, and btw i messed up i meant JRE not JDE, i know the JDE is Windows based, guess i won't be able to do anything but blind code at home and test back at work, thanks

Comment: Or do what most BlackBerry developers who use a Mac do - install Parallels with a Windows VM.

Comment: OT but... how's the performance running the simulator and/or Eclipse in Parallels? And what Mac do you use for comparison? I've been thinking about trying this out for a while but haven't had the time...

Comment: It's definitely not as fast as running it on a native top-end PC, but with a modern MBP (I have an i7 based MBP) with lots of memory, it's not too bad.

Comment: Well that might be enough of a push for me to give it a try. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse 3.6 you must use this url: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/3.6/java/
If after downloading have error because too much authentication error, i'm suggesting you must re-create bb developer zone account & login using it (Kind of annoying, coz at my country bandwidth is limited & after waiting 3 hour, the installation is failed).

Also, in copying file don't forget copy fledge from net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.30/components/. If not when i try to add the definition file JRE i got this kind of error
"Execution Environment File Property-Dee.executable must point to a valid copy offledge.exe"

Hope this is can help.

Comment: Yes i am getting the same error. Don't know how do i proceed further. If you know then please share.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh. Seems like Apple removed java 5 and below from Snow Leopard (10.6). Leopard (10.5) still supports 1.4.2 and 5.0 and 6.0. You can find them in "/Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences.app".

Comment: I meant the BlackBerry JDE not Java, i'm not having problems with that, thanks for the answer anyways :)