# How to develop Blackberry apps on Mac OS?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing iPhone and also Android applications in Apple MacBook. I want to develop Blackberry application. I am using Windows to learn for now.

Is there any software or Eclipse plugin to develop BlackBerry applications on Mac OS instead of Windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [installing BlackBerry Eclipse JDE plugin on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774832/installing-blackberry-eclipse-jde-plugin-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find something interesting/useful by looking at this question: [installing BlackBerry Eclipse JDE plugin on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774832/installing-blackberry-eclipse-jde-plugin-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: I downloaded eclipse for mac. I can able to create Blackberry project in eclipse. But I am not able to run it in simulator. I want to test the app in simulator. Please can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the current version of the Eclipse plug-in only supports OS6 and you must have a physical device connected to the computer.  I've been using Parallels to run Windows XP on my Macbook Pro and am pretty pleased.

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of using parallels. It can run in coherence mode and also skin windows to look like your mac. I use parallels and an eclipse windows plugin.