# Testing a BB application on a mac?

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

I have just started to develop for BlackBerry I was wondering is it possible to test it on the mac without having a BB

thanks

Comment: I am not a MAC user but according to [this](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/download/testing), BlackBerry's simulators are available for Windows only. I guess that  VirtualBox or any other VM software with Windows installation and BlackBerry simulators will do the job.

Comment: Damn that sucks..no wonder why BB is sufering

Comment: I suggest you to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629174/how-to-develop-blackberry-apps-on-mac-os and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774832/installing-blackberry-eclipse-jde-plugin-on-mac-os-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link for the [enviroment](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse?os=mac)
Check: "Adding the BlackBerry Update site in Eclipse (Mac)"

You can add an emulator using wine

Comment: Link to adding the emulator not working please update the links

Comment: Links dead, you'll have to search, it wasn't hard