# Appcelerator \ Titanium - Cross platform development

Tags: mobile, appcelerator

I'm looking to build a mobile application that works on iOS and BlackBerry. I have been looking at the Appcelerator platform which seems quite highly recommended but I still don't see how I can build for both platforms easily.

The problem is that it looks like for iOS it needs to be built on a MAC and for BlackBerry it needs to be build in Windows! So what would be the easiest setup to target both platforms? Would I literally just have to do the build separately on two different machines?

Answer (score 0):

This question has instructions for downloading the SDK for mac, user seems to have an issue with running the simulator however.

[How to develop Blackberry apps on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629174/how-to-develop-blackberry-apps-on-mac-os)

If that doesn't work you could always use a vm of windows on a mac and create the titanium project as a shared project between the OS and the vm