# Blackberry Eclipse plugin for Mac installation voodoo needed

Tags: macos, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Has anyone successfully installed and run the Blackberry Eclipse plugin for MacOS?

Apparently, BB has not improved their Mac support much in the last year, since there was a question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774832/installing-blackberry-eclipse-jde-plugin-on-mac-os-x) about it last year.

I've followed their instructions to the letter, but they seem to assume that all you'll ever do in Eclipse is use their plugin.  I want to move their plugin into an existing Eclipse installation.

I've copied the net.rim.* files from their Eclipse installation in to my /plugins folder, restarted, they show up in the list of installed plugins, but building an app always yields this error:

*"Failed importing native project for BlackBerry. Missing Blackberry plugin. For more details see http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp"*

Thanks.
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the secret:

point Eclipse 3.6 Hellios to the following plug-in URL: http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web

Eclipse/Help/Install New Software...   Add, enter some name and the URL above, and it works.